prometheus list labels for all metrics not having a label
I like to find all apps (here:com_name) that are missing the tenant_id label so I can add it.
I tried the following:
group ({com_name=~"id-pro-.+", tenant_id=""}) by (com_name)

But if I search any of the com_name that shows up:
{com_name="id-pro-test1-keycloak-server", tenant_id=~".+"}

I see tenant_id values all over. I believe this may be some metrics with the com_name are missing it, but I can ignore those, I like to find those that do not have this label at all.
From How to display all metrics that don't have a specific label I tried:
node_load1{com_name="id-pro-.+", not_existent_label="tenant_id"}

Resulting in an empty query.

You misunderstood that answer. not_existent_label refers to the label that doesn't exist, not some pseudo function. Your first attempt shown in question uses search for non existence labels correctly.

To get what you describe, you can get a full list of possible labels, and then exclude from it those, that have tenant I'd anywhere: group by (com_name)({com_name!=""}) unless on(com_name) group by (com_name)({com_name!="",tennant_id!=""})

@markalex, Thanks, seem to work, I've checked some metrics ant they are all missing tenant_id, group by (com_name)({com_name=~"id-pro-.+"}) unless on(com_name) group by (com_name)({com_name=~"id-pro-.+",tenant_id!=""}) Have to read up how this works :-)
